# Is it good practice to make images gray-scaled before sending them to Google Cloud Vision API for OCR?

Tags: image-processing, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I'm using Google Cloud Vision API to perform OCR on my documents. In [optimization](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files) page, there is no information about color-space of images, but for OCR processing, color depth usually doesn't matter. So instead of making images smaller than the original one, we can limit the color of documents for example in gray-scaled format and send the processed image to be OCRed.

My question is:

1- Does OCR of Vision API care about colors for example in RBG format?

2- If so, how much the accuracy will be effected by making images gray-scaled? is it worth it?

3- If not, why isn't it documented in the optimization page?

Comment: @NicEndo, probably to reduce traffic.

Comment: @NicEndo, Nakilon is right, Google Cloud Vision API has some limitation on image size (which is 4MB per image and also 8MB per request) and document says `Reducing your file size can significantly improve throughput`